# Whats the function of the resistor between MCU and its Resonator in Arduino Mega?

Tags: arduino-mega

I was looking Arduino Mega's [schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560-schematic.pdf) and I noticed a resistor between the MCU and its resonator. R3 in this image:

[image]

Why is it there and what is its function?

Comment: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=k7m3r8sckc0kmc8oda18gt0l16&topic=176297.msg1309697#msg1309697

Comment: @Gerben - This addresses R1, not R3.

Comment: Oops. Didn't even see R3. That's indeed a weird location for a resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That resistor limits the drive through the crystal.  If the power applied to the crystal is too high then the slope and phase shift at the resonant frequency will not be optimal and at really high drive levels could cause mechanical damage to the crystal (like that shattered wine glass trick).

See good instruction PDF [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiozMK9gJXRAhWKrVQKHf7WBYwQFgg4MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geyer-electronic.com%2Ffileadmin%2Fuser_upload%2Ffrequenz%2Fservice%2FQuarz-Tutorial_en_2.2_Geyer.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHvE9vkQIcqmR2YDzRe2AySD0kHWw&bvm=bv.142059868,d.cGw), section 2.1.